# Encrypted personal diary for android

Tags: android, open-source, encryption, cloud-storage

I'm looking for an application for keeping a personal diary on my Android phone. My requirements:

- All data is encrypted so that only I can access the content.
- It's open-source (I have higher trust to open-source solutions when it comes to security).
- The content is replicated to a cloud storage like Google Drive so that losing my phone doesn't mean losing all my data.

Other than that, no special features are needed, just writing text (or perhaps dictating) on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest that you should look into [Memoires: the Diary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nakvic.dromoris).

From its [website](https://sites.google.com/site/drodiary/):

> It is secured and password protected. It keeps you thoughts way from stranger's eyes, encrypting text, images and audio recordings, attached to a record. However, if you decide to publish your thoughts, you can easily send them to Google+, twitter, per email or sms in any way which is available to be used on your phone. *Memories* uses other apps to publish data, but you decide what you keep secret and what you make public.

> Memoires provides you with the functionality to synchronize data with your personal Google account

> **Main features:**
>
> - Text records
> - Unlimited amount of photos and images attached to a record. Images could be either taken with camera or imported from photo album.
> - Unlimited amount of audio recordings attached to a record.
> - Timeline, Calendar, Map and Album views. See screenshots for details.
> - Geo location fetching
> - Manual geo location setup
> - Address search
> - Navigation right from application
> - Current weather conditions
> - Lunar phases
> - Configurable fonts and font size
> - User fonts from SD card (ttf or otf fonts should be placed into /sdcard/fonts folder)
> - Multiple images per memory
> - Image description
> - Multiple tags per memory
> - Filtering by tags, locations, time
> - Mood indicator (optional)
> - List view with in-place text expand
> - Full page view
> - Image gallery view
> - Map view
> - Synchronization with users' Google account (Drive, Spreadsheet, Picasa)
> - Export of text and images to RTF or Google document
> - Export to Picasa album
> - Sharing with the other application (mail, messaging, buzz, twitter etc). Corresponding client application is required to be installed.
> - Fetch text and images from other applications which support "send to" action for easy quoting, for example from RSS reader, Internet browser, Photo Album etc.
> - Password protection
> - Encryption of text, images and audio recordings

Comment: Thanks, this would satisfy my requirements, except that it seems it's not open-source.